# Conditionally Initialise variable in XSLT

Tags: variables, xslt, initialization

I am trying to initialize variable in XSLT conditionally however I am not able to do so. Can any one please point what is the issue with this code? I use following code for this:

```
<xsl:variable name ="ProductTag">
  <xsl:if test="$prodObjType = fn:string('Style')" >
     <xsl:value-of  
                select="Data/Style[@sequence_id=$prodLatestSeq]"/>
     </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

Note: prodLatestSeq has value numeric value- I confirmed it after printing it with xsl:message.Data is of following format

```
   <Data>
       <Style sequence_id="1">
       </Style>

       <Style sequence_id="3">
       </Style>

       <Style sequence_id="4">
       </Style>

    </Data>
```

Comment: What's not going correctly? It looks like the `<Style>` elements in your example are empty, so `$ProductTag` would have a blank value.

Comment: Style elements are correctly populated in XML. I get this value correctly if I use<xsl:variable name="ProductTag" select="Data/Style[@sequence_id = $prodLatestSeq]"/>. So I am facing issue if i do conditionaly initialise it. Somehow "select" statement is not executed correctly

Comment: Are you sure that it's not the `test` expression that's not evaluating as you expect?  What happens if you use `test="true"`? What happens if you use `test="fn:string($prodObjType) = 'Style'"`?

Comment: The only issue with your code is that what it does is something different from what you want it to do. Since you haven't told us what you want it to do, we can't really tell you how to change it.

Comment: Thanks for your responses Michael and Rishe. I could evaluate my xPath expression with following code successfully. <xsl:variable name="ProductTag" select="if($prodObjType eq 'Style') then Data/Style[@sequence_id = $prodLatestSeq] else 'unknown'"/>. I feel somehow xPath evaluation was not happening with my earlier code. Still i wonder what i have done differently then earlier version of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Could this be what you're looking for?

```
<xsl:variable name ="ProductTag">   
  <xsl:if test="$prodObjType = fn:string('Style')" >
    <xsl:value-of select="Data/Style[@sequence_id=$prodLatestSeq]/@sequence_id"/>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

You're missing the `/@sequence_id` part in the end